# Image and inverse image of a set problem

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to answer the following problem.

"Give an example of a function $\textit{f}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and sets $\textit{X}$, $\textit{Y} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\textit{f}(\textit{X}) = \textit{Y}$, but $\textit{f}^{-1}(\textit{X}) \neq \textit{Y}$."

a. Is it safe to say that I am looking for $\textit{f}$, $\textit{X}$, and $\textit{Y}$ satisfying the above condition such that $\textit{f}(\textit{X}) \neq \textit{f}^{-1}(\textit{X})$?

b. Does my answer below satisfy such conditions:

Consider the function $\textit{f}$ : $\text{{1, 2, 3}} \rightarrow \text{{4, 5, 6}}$ from $\textit{X}=\text{{1, 2, 3}}$ to $\textit{Y}=\text{{4, 5, 6}}$ defined by $f(x) = x + 3$.

Thanks in advance and regards.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, I double checked and it is what the problem states.

Comment: Assuming that $f(n) := 2 \times n$ we have that $f^{-1}(n) := \dfrac n 2$. If so, it works: $f^{-1}(1)= \dfrac 1 2 \notin Y$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Does this mean that your answer to my first question is "yes"?

Comment: You didn't give a function. $f:\{1,2,3\} \to \{4,5,6\}$ doesn't define a function. You just specified the domain and codomain of $f$, but not $f$ itself.

Comment: @jjagmath I edited the post.

Comment: That's a rather bizarre question as the image of set has no bearing on the preimage.  In fact, I think it'd be harder to come up with an example where $f(X) = f^{-1}(X)$.  So far as I can tell your example is just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ defined by

$$f(x) =x^2 $$

$X=\{-1\}$ and, $Y=\{1\}$

$f(X) =\{1\}=Y$

$f^{-1}(X) =\emptyset$

Comment: Can you give details how were you able to get $\textit{f}^{-1}(\textit{X})$?

Comment: $x\in f^{-1}\{-1\} \implies f(x) =-1$ ,$\space\space $ no $x\in \Bbb{R}$ satisfy $x^{2}=-1$

Comment: is my own answer above (that which uses {1,2,3} and {4,5,6} correct?

Comment: @R.L.D.Daguro You didn't give any function.